# Mongoose paginate page count append with docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I am using mongoose-paginate plugin for pagination. I couldn't send the pageCount as a response along with the data. Here is the code

```
function(req,res) {
    MySchema.paginate({}, { page: req.params.pageIndex, limit: 10 }, function(err, MyOutput, pageCount){
        res.jsonp(Users)
    })
}
```

Is it possible to append the the pageCount along with the MyOutput and response with that? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with your response before sending it back. Something like this:

```
res.jsonp({pageCount: req.params.pageIndex, output: MyOutPut});
```

Instead of just sending your output, you are creating a new object with two keys (`pageCount` and `output`). Your query result is inside output. Your pageCount which was added to your url params, is now inside pageCount.